# John von Neumann's thinking process

Tags: mathematicians, von-neumann

I'm interested in John von Neumann these days. So I searched [this file](https://www.ams.org/notices/201302/rnoti-p154.pdf). And I read books *The Man from the Future* and *John Von Neumann: The Scientific Genius Who Pioneered the Modern Computer, Game Theory, Nuclear Deterrence, and Much More*

In particular, [this file](https://www.ams.org/notices/201302/rnoti-p154.pdf) provides a direct assessment of Freeman Dyson's von Neumann's thinking process. (p.1 right side)

> Johnny’s unique gift as a mathematician was to transform problems in all areas of mathematics into problems of logic. He was able to see intuitively the logical essence of problems and then to use the simple rules of logic to solve the problems. His first paper is a fine example of his style of thinking. A theorem which appears to belong to geometry, restricting the possible positions of points where some function of a complex variable is equal to zero, is transformed into a statement of pure logic. All the geometrical
> complications disappear and the proof of the theorem becomes short and easy. In the whole paper there are no calculations, only verbal definitions and logical deductions.

And If you see the book, *John Von Neumann: The Scientific Genius Who Pioneered the Modern Computer, Game Theory, Nuclear Deterrence, and Much More*, it cites von Neumann's mathematical hobby,

> He used to find out the thinking process of math masters such as "Galileo" and "Newton", the background of the idea, and the reason for the failure and was interested.

Are all of the above informations true? And explain in detail the way von Neumann treated mathematics.

Comment: If you don't already know of it, you may be interested in [*The legend of John von Neumann*](https://www.jstor.org/stable/2319080) by Paul R. Halmos (1973). See pp. 386-387 for the story about how he responded when hearing about the fly and bicycles problem (reprinted at top of [this web page](https://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=1866783). FYI, there's surely a Wikipedia page for this problem (has many variations), but I can't find it. However, I posted a lot of references about it in [this 17 October 2006 sci.math post](https://groups.google.com/g/sci.math/c/4u1A5g_coew/m/iir4j8l6vjQJ).

Comment: Stanisław Ulam's 1976 book **Adventures of a Mathematician** discusses von Neumann a lot, and my impression of what Ulam conveys about von Neumann in this book is someone with an inhuman lightening calculator ability and immediate grasp of concepts, but whose creativity is within the human range (but nonetheless extremely high).

Comment: The following obituary seems to contain a number of relevant observations but is too voluminous for me to summarize on the double: Stanislaw Ulam, "John von Neumann, 1903-1957." *Bulletin of the American Mathematical Society*, Vol. 64, No. 3, Part 2, May 1958, pp. 1-49 ([scan](https://www.ams.org/journals/bull/1958-64-03/S0002-9904-1958-10189-5/S0002-9904-1958-10189-5.pdf))

Comment: Please provide authors and editorials of books if possible, also add the titles of the files that you linked (that way if the link goes rotten we can find it back)